# Rails 5, login with Microsoft Account (Office 365)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, office365, microsoft-account

I have already implemented [this](https://github.com/jasonjoh/o365-tutorial). For now I can get calendar, inbox, contacts.

And now I want to login as Office365 account. It means I want to get user's email & name, ... something like `gem 'omniauth-facebook'` when login with Facebook.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance! Happy coding :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow this sample application
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/ruby-connect-rest-sample

It's working fine with gem

```
omniauth_src = 'https://github.com/cbales/omniauth-microsoft_graph'
gem 'omniauth-microsoft_v2_auth', git: omniauth_src
```